# OPS 0855 Gemini B Separation

Tags: sub-orbital, project-gemini, titan-rocket, transtage

On 3 November 1966 a modified [Titan IIC](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Titan_IIIC) launched from LC-40 in Cape Canaveral. This launch would be the only launch as part of the [Manned Orbiting Laboratory](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Manned_Orbiting_Laboratory) program. Designated [OPS 0855](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/OPS_0855) the vehicle consisted of an earlier flown Gemini capsule, OV4-1 and OV1-6. As the mission profile reads:

> OPS 0855 was the primary payload of Titan IIIC 3C-9, The Gemini B prototype capsule, known as Gemini SC-2, was flown on the same rocket, and was released **onto a suborbital trajectory during launch**. The adaptor connecting the Gemini spacecraft to OPS 0855 contained three additional spacecraft, two OV4-1 satellites, and OV1-6. **These were released into low Earth orbit.**

And another [source](https://space.skyrocket.de/doc_sdat/ov4-3.htm) reads

> The satellite was spin stabilized after Transtage shutdown. On the upper end, a Gemini B capsule was mounted during launch and **released on a suborbital trajectory**. Also inside the Gemini B adapter were three small satellites: OV1 6, OV4 1R and OV4 1T. OV4-3 worked for 30 days (75 days were planned).

So first the Gemini capsule was released and then the second stage would burn continuing going into a stable orbit around the Earth. How did they make sure that the Gemini capsule had enough distance from the second stage before they lighted its engines and prevent it into crashing one and another? Did the Gemini capsule used it's own propulstion system to target itself away from the Transtage?

Also any other general information about this unique mission is welcomed

[image: OV4-3]

Picture of The OV4-3 (Orbiting Vehicle 4-3) and the Titan Transtage

Comment: If the MOL had ever been flown, the astronauts would have accessed the lab by crawling through a hatch cut in the Gemini heat shield. One of the objectives on this mission was to test the integrity of the hatch. When the capsule was recovered, it was found that the hatch had been welded shut by the re-entry heating but it had not affected the heat shield as a whole and the concept was valid.

Comment: Great question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for a really interesting question - I'd looked into the MOL test launch a couple of times, but never considered this.

The answer is found in [SSSLV-5 NO. 9 POST FIRING FLIGHT TEST REPORT (FINAL EVALUATION REPORT) AND MOL-EFT FINAL FLIGHT TEST REPORT](https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/pdfs/AD0378020.pdf) paragraph 3.1.3.7 Gemini Separation

I expected to see small solid motors push the capsule off - but no. The opposite happened. It happened at a time when the third stage was not firing, and ...

> The Gemini separation maneuver involved decelerating
> the transtage - MOL - Adapter (TMA) away from Gemini by the
> use of 5 retro-rockets, and pitching the TMA nose up by use
> of the asymmetric arrangement of the retro-rockets and
> pitch-roll mixing of the ACS rockets. The proper separation
> rates were achieved, but the TMA pitched nose-down during
> retro-rocket firing instead of nose-up.

ACS = Attitude Control System

Diagram from the document showing the location of the retro-rockets (annotations mine)

[image: schematic drawing of the upper stage and payloads of the MOL test vehicle with the retro-rockets annotated.]

Here is a summary of the timeline. The document is full of exquisite detail if you want more. Time is in seconds, rounded off by me.

- 0    Liftoff on SRBs
- 110  Stage I engine ignition
- 122  SRB separation
- 258  Stage I engine shutdown / Stage II engine start / separation
- 459  Stage II engine shutdown
- 469  Stage II / III separation
- 472  Stage III Burn 1 ignition
- **779  Stage III Burn 1 shutdown**
- **810  Gemini separation**
- **813  Stage III retro-thrust**
- **844  Stage III Burn 2 ignition**
- 886  Stage III Burn 2 shutdown
- 3182  Stage III Burn 3 ignition
- 3188  Stage III Burn 3 shutdown

Comment: Thank you very much for the great answer. Never thought I would get a great explanation on this unique mission.